# Rails 3.1 and the lack of a service layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm writing an hotel-like app in Rails 3.1 and I'm new to Rails.
I'd need some advice about how write what is normally managed in the service layer of an app.

The app needs some service to calculate the price, and this methods have to be available for more than one controller. Till now I put all this stuff in a controller but now I have to get it out from there and really I' don't know how and where.

I thought about writing a helper and include it in the controller but I dislike this solution because helpers should only help to render stuff in the view and they shouldn't mess with the business layer related tasks.

How would you code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a folder named `services`

```
/app
  /controllers
  /services
    calculation_service.rb
```

Then you use it on your controllers like this:

```
def show
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
  @total = CalculationService.calculate_sum(@model.price, @model.subtotal)
end
```

Comment: I did it yet but I couldn't understand if CalculationService would be a class or something else (because I'm quite sure it's not class). Seems to me that Mixin is what suites to my needs

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even do this in the controller.  I would push the logic to your model if possible. If it's required in multiple models,  I'd create a mixin in your lib folder and include it in each model.

Comment: I put in the controller just to show something the works to the client. From my point of view, put it in the controller is wrong in the same way as put in the model (and in this case there is even no Price model). Anyway, Mixin seems to be the solution. Thanks a lot, I didn't know about them